# Code for fetching a clob larger than 32k from db to an apex Rich text editor

Tags: clob, oracle-apex-5

I am using APEX 5.0. I need some code for get a clob from db and save it back to db, the clob will be larger than 32k sometimes. I am using APEX Rich text editor (CKEditor4). 
PL/SQL is ok for me but javascript i new to me.

As soon i use the builtin PL/SQL in APEX i am limited to 32k so that don't work. I get "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error" as soon the clob is larger than 32k.
I have tried a plugin "Clob loader" witch works fine (via an collection) inside APEX but i cant find any way to load or save the collection to/from db.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a working solution from
"Dan McGhan's Oracle APEX Blog" so i can read and save the clob from/to db.
[CKEditor and Those Pesky CLOBs](http://www.danielmcghan.us/2010/02/ckeditor-and-those-pesky-clobs.html)
It's not possible to manipulate clobs inside APEX if bigger than 32k, but outside it works fine.